# How do you handle the situation where the residual variance is very high compared to the other variance parameter estimates?

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection

**Context**

An experiment in agronomy whose aim is to investigate the possible effect of a treatment, with 13 possible levels, on the height of trees.

**Model**

$
Y_{ijk} = \mu_{\cdot \cdot \cdot} + \alpha_{i} + \beta_{j} + \gamma_{k(j)} + (\alpha \beta)_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}
$

- $Y_{ijk}$ is the response for the tree lying in the $k$th row of the $j$th bloc when it has received the $i$th treatment,
- $\mu_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}$ is an overall constant,
- $\alpha_{i}$ are the fixed treatment effects,
- $\beta_{j}$ are the random bloc effects,
- $\gamma_{k(j)}$ are the random row (nested within bloc) effects,
- $(\alpha \beta)_{ij}$ are the random treatment-bloc interaction effects,
- $\epsilon_{ijk}$ are random error terms.

**Two important features**

- There is a lot of heterogeneity in response within each treatment.
- The interaction $(\alpha \gamma)_{ik(j)}$ cannot be estimated because there is no replicate.

**Partial results**

The residual variance is much much higher than the variances of the different random effects. As a consequence, a much simpler model without random effect is selected based on the AIC.

EDIT relative to Nick Sabbe's comment: The simpler model I am talking about is

$Y_{ijk} = \mu_{\cdot \cdot \cdot} + \alpha_{i} + \epsilon_{ijk}
$

**Question**

My interpretation is that the residual variance actually contains two parts: the residual variance itself, and the interaction that cannot be estimated. Now, intuitively, I think that that interaction cannot be simply ignored. Hence, I would not compare my model with a simpler model without random effect. **Do you agree with that?**

Comment: If some of the terms in your model cannot be estimated, how _would_ you compare it with models that can be estimated? You should not even be able to calculate the AIC without having the MLE for all your parameters.